# Bit-shifting with Int64

Tags: c#, .net, bit-shift, int64

An Int64 variable needs to be shifted. I am parsing pseudo mathematical functions from a database file. The Variables are uint32 or int32 so i did put them into an Int64 to handle them equally without loosing anything. In one of my treenodes i need to bitshift Int64.

Unfortunately the shift operator does not apply to Int64. Is there a standard way of bit shifting Int64 that i am not aware of?

```
//Int32 Example works
int a32 = 1;
int b32 = 2;
int c32 = a32 >> b32;

//Int64 Example does not compile
Int64 a64 = 1;
Int64 b64 = 2;
Int64 c64 = a64 >> b64; //invalid operator
```

Comment: Can you just store b64 as `int`? Will it make a difference?

Comment: could you use UInt64 (unsigned int)?

Comment: the right hand operand is the number of bits to shift the left hand operand. so shifting by an Int64 makes no sense...

Comment: @codesparkle i agree, but a number like that could come from the database. i solved it now by converting to int32.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the right-hand operand of the right-shift operator (in C#) always takes an `int`, even if the left-hand operand is not an `int`.

Official details here in [C# Specification on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Nothing else would make sense, since shifting more than 64 places just shifts everything out of existence anyway.

Comment: @Dervall But along those lines, even an `int` is overkill too :)

Comment: @reuben a byte would do, but that would cause slower code since the processor is optimized to work with 32 bits, or 64 bits.

Comment: ok - it works with an int... but theretically my users could write UINT32.MAX as a value and my code would do something stupid...
i admit its unlikely.. i will leave a TODO in my code to drive future programmers mad.

Answer (score 9):

The number of bits to be shifted must be an `int`.

Eg:

```
int shift = 3;
long foo = 123456789012345;
long bar = foo >> shift;
```