# About the maximum size of Enum Flag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I have a question.

I am currently studying Flag among Enum functions.
And then I was wondering, what is the maximum size that I can designate as Enum Flag?

I'm currently marking the flag as below.

```
A = 1 << 0,
B = 1 << 1,
C = 1 << 2,
ZZZ = 1 << MaxSize(?)
```

I'm curious about the value of Max size.

Thank you for reading it, and there may be grammatical errors because it is translated. :-)

Comment: The biggest backing-type for an `enum` is `Int64`  and `UInt64`, so you can have _at most_ 64 distinct individual bits as flags - but you can have synonyms (enum members with the same value but different names) and arbitrary bitwise combinations as their own members.

Comment: @Dai Then is it possible until ZZZ = 1 < < 64?

Comment: Actually `1<<63`. `1<<64` would be `0`.

Comment: @DStanley no .. `1 << 31`. An `int` has 32 bits so after that you are just starting over. The bitshift operators only work on and with `int` so you will never go beyond `1<<31`

Comment: @derHugo _"The bitshift operators only work on and with int"_ - uhh, what? I can use `<<` and `>>` with `Int64` operands on the right-hand just fine, and shift by 33 or 63 bits: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MlfZ6A

Comment: @Dai well, yes .. but not if you wrote `1 << 64` .. that's what I mean .. because these are still `int` and will return `int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What follows are random thoughts of mine in no particular order:

- Required reading:

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum
  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum

---

- In .NET, an `enum` type is essentially a set of named-constants for the enum's *underlying-type*.

  - Though the C# compiler does not allow implicit conversion between an enum's values and its *underlying-type* (except for `0`).
- This is documented in the .NET Common Language Infrastructure specification: [ECMA-335, 5th edition (2010), page 34](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf).
- In C#, an `enum` can use any of the of .NET's built-in integer types as an *underlying-type* (as of .NET 5 in 2021, we're still limited to the same 8 integer bytes as we were back in 2001, but we *might* get a real `Int128` eventually, but that's still years away):

  - `Byte` and `SByte` (1 octet: 8 bits, values `0-255` and `-128` to `127` respectively).
  - `UInt16`  and `Int16` (2 bytes aka 2 octets: 16 bits, values `0-65535` and `-32768` to `32767` respectively).
  - `UInt32`  and `Int32` (4 bytes, 32 bits, etc).
  - `UInt64`  and `Int64` (8 bytes, 64 bits, etc).
  - (I believe that the .NET spec does *technically* allow `Boolean`/`bool` to be used as an enum underlying-type, but C# does not allow this).

---

It's immediately obvious that both `Int64` and `UInt64` (aka `long` and `ulong` for people who are allergic to the shift-key) offer the widest "space" for bit values: there's 64 bits to play with, after all - while the other *underlying-types* only grant you 32, 16, or a measly 8 bits.

---

There is no limit on the number of members in an `enum`, but obviously enums with smaller *underlying-types* will exhaust their set of possible values sooner than bigger types and will eventually repeat themselves.

`enum` types can have multiple members with different names that share the same integer value, however internally the CLR has no way of knowing one from the other.

---

> what is the maximum size that I can designate as Enum Flag?

If you're referring to the *underlying-type* then the straightforward answer is either `Int64` (`long`) or `UInt64` (`ulong`).

If you're asking about the maximum *value* that an enum member can have, then that would be `YourUnderlyingType.MaxValue`, for example:

```
enum IntSizedEnum : Int32
{
    LargestValue = Int32.MaxValue
}

enum BiggerEnum : UInt64
{
    EvenLargerLargestValue = UInt64.MaxValue
}
```

If you're asking about the number of bits set, then if you use `Int64` or `UInt64` you can get 64 bits, or individual flags - and even define them on a bit-by-bit basis with bit-literals, for example:

```
enum BiggerEnum : UInt64
{
    All64Bits = 0b_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111
}
```

With flags, you can go a bit crazy:

```
[Flags]
enum BiggerEnum : UInt64
{
    FlagsCombination = Bit_32 | Bit_33 | Bit_34,

    Bit_0  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001,
    Bit_1  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010,
    Bit_2  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000100,
    Bit_3  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00001000,
    Bit_4  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00010000,
    Bit_5  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00100000,
    Bit_6  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_01000000,
    Bit_7  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_10000000,
    Bit_8  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001_00000000,
    Bit_9  = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010_00000000,
    Bit_10 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000100_00000000,
    Bit_11 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00001000_00000000,
    Bit_12 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00010000_00000000,
    Bit_13 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00100000_00000000,
    Bit_14 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_01000000_00000000,
    Bit_15 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_10000000_00000000,
    Bit_16 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_17 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_18 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000100_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_19 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00001000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_20 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00010000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_21 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00100000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_22 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_01000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_23 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_10000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_24 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_25 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_26 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000100_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_27 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00001000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_28 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00010000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_29 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00100000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_30 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_01000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_31 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_32 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_33 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_34 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000100_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_35 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00001000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_36 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00010000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_37 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00100000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_38 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_01000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_39 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_40 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_41 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000010_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_42 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000100_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_43 = 0b00000000_00000000_00001000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_44 = 0b00000000_00000000_00010000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_45 = 0b00000000_00000000_00100000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_46 = 0b00000000_00000000_01000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_47 = 0b00000000_00000000_10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_48 = 0b00000000_00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_49 = 0b00000000_00000010_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_50 = 0b00000000_00000100_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_51 = 0b00000000_00001000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_52 = 0b00000000_00010000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_53 = 0b00000000_00100000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_54 = 0b00000000_01000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_55 = 0b00000000_10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_56 = 0b00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_57 = 0b00000010_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_58 = 0b00000100_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_59 = 0b00001000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_60 = 0b00010000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_61 = 0b00100000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_62 = 0b01000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000,
    Bit_63 = 0b10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000
}
```

```
// Usage:
BiggerEnum value = default;
value |= BiggerEnum.Bit_32 | BiggerEnum.Bit_33 | BiggerEnum.Bit_34;

Console.WriteLine( value == BiggerEnum.FlagsCombination ); // true
Console.WriteLine( value ); // 30064771072
```

...but you really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that if you go "manual" this actually works!

Answer (score 1):

In the way you want to use it with bitshifting it would be

```
1 << 31
```

which is

```
-2147483648
```

and well an `int` has exactly 32 bits so if you do

```
1 << 32
```

meaning you take the value 1

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

and now shift all the bits 32 times to the left it just results again in `1` or

```
1 << 0
```

It would be no use to change the underlying enum type to e.g. `ulong`. At least not using bitshift operators since the bitshift operator always only can bitshift **`int`** values (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343686/bit-shifting-with-int64/11343707)).

---

If you really want to go crazy look at [Dai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007253/7111561)! **Manually** you can actually expand the flag to use the undelying type `ulong` and have up to `64` values.